# Can you use a range for comparison of selectedindex on a combobox?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a combobox binded from values from a database and I want to check if the selectedindex is either 0 - 5 and then do something based on that.

I know I can use

`if cboTrainingType.selectedindex = 0 or cboTrainingType.selectedindex = 1 or .....`

I was wondering if there is a way to just specify if the cboTrainingType.selectedindex = range(0,5) or something simliar ?

Comment: `If cbo.SelectedIndex >-1 AndAlso cbo.SelectedIndex <=5 Then...`  (assuming 5, the max, is inclusive)

Comment: Much cleaner, thanks